# jQuery Plugins for Full Screen slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, slideshow, fullscreen

Searching the web, i found many plugins with javascript/jquery (maximage, supersized, superslides etc), for present images in a full screen slideshow.

What is the best plugin? I would like a plugin that works in Firefox, chrome, IE10, and responsive

Answer (score 1):

Try this list site, I think it's nice :

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CSS3FullscreenSlideshow/index.html

http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/FullscreenSlideshowAudio/